# Could not find a declaration file for module '@schematics/angular/utility/project'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-schematics

I want to use the `buildDefaultPath` method usually available in `'@schematics/angular/utility/project'` to write an Angular schematics.

I installed the package with `npm i @schematics/angular` and tried to import it like this: `import { buildDefaultPath } from '@schematics/angular/utility/project';`.

However, I get "Could not find a declaration file for module '@schematics/angular/utility/project'."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the missing function in:

`import { buildDefaultPath } from '@schematics/angular/utility/workspace';`

It was removed from `@schematics/angular/utility/project` because it was a duplicate of the method in `workspace` file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was removed in version 10+.

Downgrading to 9.1.12 got me the `buildDefaultPath` method I wanted.

```
npm uninstall @schematics/angular
npm i @schematics/angular@9.1.12
```